# Listbox values are not persistent when append through jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listbox

I am appending listbox items through Jquery. They are succesfully inserted and am able to see it in UI. But when accessing in code behind, listbox items are showing as zero.

Here is my JQuery Code.

```
 var options = $("#<%=lbAccountExecutives.ClientID%> option");
                var alreadyExist = false;
                $(options).each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == EmployeeName) {                          
                        alreadyExist = true;
                        return;
                    }                      
                });
                if (!alreadyExist) {
                    $("#<%=lbAccountExecutives.ClientID%>").append('<option>' + EmployeeName + '</option>');

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value by creating a hidden field(*it may have syntax errors*):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelectedValue runat="server" />
```

after appending the options to listbox, to keep data after postback do this:

```
$('#<%=lbAccountExecutives.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=hfselectedValue.ClientID%>').val());
```

To get the selected value from code behind

```
$('#<%=lbAccountExecutives.ClientID%>').change(function(){
    $('#<%=hfselectedValue.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=lbAccountExecutives.ClientID%>').val())
});
```

Now in code behind you have access to value :

```
string hiddenvalue = hfselectedValue.value;
```